# python api for postgresql pg_dump*, restore commands

Tags: python, postgresql

Is there a python library that contains the functionality of the pg_dump, pg_dumpall and restore commands?  I want to have the ability to handle exceptions where the standard commands do not allow for that level of control.

Is there anything out here that can help me?

Answer (score 1):

You could try [psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/). It's a python api to postgres, and you can use the [copy_from](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from) and [copy_to](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_to) methods on the cursor to do it with `StringIO` objects and do it all in memory, or just with the disk.

This is only good for data though, i believe.

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't solve the problem, unless you're willing to go through the trouble of implementing your very own backup/restore routines.