# Dump contents of PostgreSQL database programmatically in python (w/out shell scripts)

Tags: python, database, postgresql, pg-dump

How can one dump a PostgreSQL database programmatically, inside Python (or another language, if possible) without executing shell scripts.

Is this possible with psychopg2 or SQLAlchemy or some other library?

I want to dump **all contents** of the database, **not** just the schema.
I do not want to dump the contents of just a query.

Currently I am using
`pg_dump -h localhost -U user -d db > db_dump.sql`,
however I would like to make use of a library to do this with python code.

The solutions I have already found typically resort to something along the lines of:

`os.system(" pg_dump -h localhost -U user -d db > db_dump.sql ")`

however this just asks the host machine to run the C implementation of pg_dump.

Similarly, I notice one can dump the contents of a **query** using something like:

`cursor.execute(SELECT x FROM t)`

`f = open(db_dump.sql)`

`for row in cursor:`

`f.write("insert into t values (" + str(row) + ");")`

However I want to save the contents of the **entire database**, not just a single query.

Can it be done with python directly?

Comment: You can't, you will need to use the `pg_dump` command.

Comment: You would have to interface Python to the underlying libraries, and possibly write your own implementation of `pg_dump` in Python, see [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29020887/how-to-get-the-equivalent-of-pg-dump-s-dbname-in-python-psycopg2) (note the mention of libpq).  Another [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605051/python-api-for-postgresql-pg-dump-restore-commands).